# Click event is not firing sometimes

Tags: events, click, createjs, easeljs

I have a sprite in my html5 game and it appears on the screen for a couple of seconds. User has to click it quickly before it's disappeared from the screen.

Hovewer every 3rd click (not literally 3rd, just approximately) is not fired.. 
Game is being handled in 'tick' function.

Here is a code snippet of click event subscribing and handling:

```
game_props.defenceBtnSprite.addEventListener("click", t.onDefenceClicked);
...
    onDefenceClicked: function()
    {
         console.log("clicked!");
    },
```

What would you check first to address this issue?

Comment: Hi Jefferey, can you provide an example link?

Comment: If you are using OOP, with prototype methods, I would recommend using `on` in place of `addEventListener`, which allows you to pass scope to your handlers. http://www.createjs.com/docs/easeljs/classes/EventDispatcher.html#method_on

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, Lanny. It didn't help though.